Ideas on how to do ray-tracing for a volume of voxels
I work on medical imaging and would like to use Vulkan ray-tracing to perform the following:
I currently have a volume of voxels (around 500 each dimension) and I want to trace rays from the camera through this volume (a uniform 3D grid) onto a detector plane's pixel opposite the camera. This also needs to be done for multiple angles around the volume (usually 0-180 degrees). The camera is always upright and rotates around the volume, with the volume between the camera and detector. A ray will accumulate the values in every voxel that it intersects and the final pixel value will be that sum.
I have already written a compute shader in Vulkan to do it and it performs reasonably well, like within 4-5 seconds to finish, including allocating memory for the voxels and output images etc. I don't need this to be in real-time speeds, but I just want to see if using ray-tracing hardware offers any improvements.
First, I am unsure how to construct the Acceleration Structure for the volume. I think all I need is just one BLAS (bottom level acceleration structure) to hold all the voxels, and a TLAS (top level) to refer to the BLAS.
As for the VkAccelerationStructureGeometryKHR's VkGeometryTypeKHR, I guess it's going to be VK_GEOMETRY_TYPE_AABBS_KHR. And then I will populate VkAccelerationStructureGeometryDataKHR
with all the voxels as VkAabbPositionsKHR.
Now for the shaders, I am coding in Slang. My first idea is to use the existing compute shader but do the ray-tracing with a RayQuery.
    RayDesc cameraRay = RayDesc(optCenter.xyz, 0, normDir, 1e6);
    RayQuery query = RayQuery<RAY_FLAG_NONE>();
    query.TraceRayInline(topLevelAS, RAY_FLAG_SKIP_TRIANGLES, 0xff, cameraRay);

    float payLoad = 0.f;
    while(query.Proceed()) 
    {
        uint primitiveIndex = query.CandidateRayPrimitiveIndex();
        // Logic to convert the primitive index to voxel indices (i, j, k)
        payLoad += voxels.SampleLevel(uint3(i, j, k), 0.f);
    }

It seems like AABBs fall under procedural geometry, so each call to rayQuery.Proceed() will process one intersected voxel.
I don't think I should commit any candidate hits, otherwise tmax gets updated nearer and the ray cannot intersect other voxels further ahead. The loop should just continue and ignore the intersection. Once it process all intersections, the loop should terminate by itself.
If that doesn't work, I will have to use the ray-tracing pipeline.
I think I will need a ray generation shader for the camera ray, and a any-hit shader to accumulate the voxel values.
Here's my pseudo-code.
[[vk::binding(0, 0)]]
RaytracingAccelerationStructure topLevelAS;
[[vk::binding(0, 0)]]
Sampler3D<float> voxels;

struct RayPayload {
    float value;
};

[shader("raygen")]
void RayGenerationShader() {
    // Ray origin and direction logic goes here
    RayDesc cameraRay = RayDesc(rayOrigin, 0.f, rayDirection, 1e6);

    RayPayload payLoad;
    payLoad.value = 0.f;

    // Trace the ray
    TraceRay<RayPayload>(topLevelAS, RAY_FLAG_NONE, 0xFF, 0, 1, 0, cameraRay, payLoad);
}

[shader("anyhit")]
void AnyHitShader(inout RayPayload payLoad) {
    // You can accumulate or discard intersections here
    uint primitiveIndex = PrimitiveIndex();
    // Logic to convert the primitive index to voxel indices (i, j, k)
    payLoad.value += voxels.SampleLevel(uint3(i, j, k), 0.f);
    IgnoreHit();
}

For both approaches, I suppose the voxel AABBs need to be specified in a fixed order for the conversion of primitive index to 3D voxel indices to work.
Please let me know if my ideas are fundamentally wrong.
